# NReco HTML to PDF turn off Table of Contents generation

Tags: c#, nreco

I'm trying to set up NReco HTML to PDF generation and having an issue.  It generates the PDF but when I open the PDF with adobe reader, it automatically opens the "Bookmarks" side tab consuming quite a bit of screen real estate (about 1/3 of the window).

This is unnecessary, because the PDF is one page long.  From what I can tell, this is because the PDF has a table of contents generated by taking the HTML header elements.

I updated my code to attempt to turn of table of contents generation:

```
        var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter
        {
            GenerateToc = false
        };

        var byteArray = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(emailHtmlBody);

        var memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        return memStream;
```

but making this change seems to have no effect.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it automatically opens the "Bookmarks" side tab

this is not a table of contents in fact; in terms of wkhtmltopdf (which is internally used by NReco.PdfGenerator) this is called 'outline' and you can disable its generation by H1-H6 tags in the following way:

```
htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlArgs = " --no-outline ";
```

Complete list of wkhtmltopdf options may be found here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt